# display an array in a multi-columns html table

Tags: html, arrays, laravel

I have an array of twenty elements (key-> value) as follows: 'Arr' => ['1st'  => 'xxx', '2nd' => 'ccc', '3rd'  => 'sss', '4th'  => 'ddd', ..... '20th'  => 'hhh']
I want to display this array in a html table of 10 rows and 4 columns as follows:

| 1st   | xxx    | 11th   | jjj

| 2nd   | ccc    | 12th   | fff

.

.

.

| 10th  | lll    | 20th   | hhh

when trying @foreach loop ( @foreach($Arr as $key => $value)  {{$key}}{{$code}}@endforeach), I obtain a table of 20 rows and not what is desired.
Your help is much appreciated !

Comment: This is not a `JavaScript` question. This is related to `php` I believe.

Comment: Please add an example on what you've tried so far including html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to (2 for) loop for that.
because you want to print a table.

```
<?php
   $k=0;
   for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
   ?>
   <tr>
       <?php
       for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
       ++$k;
       ?>
       <td><?php print $k;?></td>
       <?php
       }
       ?>
   </tr>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
```